# How to implement Custom NSURLProtocol for WKWebView in ionic?

Tags: ios, ionic3, wkwebview

My iOS Application need to decrypt some HTML pages; that is opening with iframe from a special folder.
Now I need to Apply NSURLProtocol for that.

How can I do the same in WKWebView.

Below is my code Snippet that was working fine in UIWebview:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];


    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[LPProtocol class]];


    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

LpProtocol is where I am handling the custom protocol rules

```
   @interface LPProtocol () <NSURLConnectionDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end

@implementation LPProtocol
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
///....
}
```

etc etc..

Can any one suggest me any way